# Null reference on valid dynamic from deserialized json file

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

## Content

Hey there,

I am using the nuget package of `Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3` and got some trouble with parsing a JSON file onto other objects

The project itself is for conversion of the JSON file into a XML file with a different structure

while executing the code (see the snippet at the end), i am getting a `Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference` exception, which indeed is true as when hovering the dynamic `input.submitter.hierarchies` you will be presented with a "NULL"

however... when checking the same inside of the watch window or immediate window, i get the proper JObject

Question now is: how to get this fixed?

## Code Snippets

JSON File:

```
{
    "submitter": {
        "hierachies": [{
        }]
    }
}
```

C# code:

```
dynamic input;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(jsonFile))
{
    input = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd(), new JsonLoadSettings() { CommentHandling = CommentHandling.Ignore, LineInfoHandling = LineInfoHandling.Ignore });
}
var obj = new SomeObject();
obj.Field = input.submitter.hierarchies[0].SomeProperty
```

Comment: You simply have a typo, missing `r` letter. `hierachies` is not `hierarchies`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo in C# code.. Your Json file contains `hierachies` wheres the c# code decodes it to `hierarchies` It must me the same.

Try this code:

```
dynamic input;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(jsonFile))
{
    input = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd(), new JsonLoadSettings() { CommentHandling = CommentHandling.Ignore, LineInfoHandling = LineInfoHandling.Ignore });
}
var obj = new SomeObject();
obj.Field = input.submitter.hierachies[0].SomeProperty
```

Comment: i knew it was something obvious :facepalm: thanks :3